# AttachmentIds are different when querying from OfficeJs API and EWS

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-store

We have built an Outlook addin using the Office JavaScript API for outlook. Our addin has a feature where the user can choose to save the attachment on the email from the addin pane. We get all the attachment Ids on email Item using the office JS API `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments`.

We then extract the Authentication token for using on the back-end to access emails.

In the Backend (.net Core) we make an EWS Call (`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService`) to extract the attachment on the email using the token. It gets the attachment details. 95% of the times the attachment Ids from EWS match the attachment Ids from Office JS API. However in a few instances, the attachmentId from EWS is different from attachment id in officeJS.

Does anyone know what are the conditions when the `attachmentId` could change between the officeJS and EWS calls?

Edit:

This is the Item ID for the email that we get from the OfficeJS API.

```
AAMkADRjMDhiMjI1LWZiMDYtNDFjOS1hODY1LWNjYWI4ODIyNTdjZQBGAAAAAAD6BIgnGKX9T7ArUySXdtR8BwAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AAANunoYAAAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AADX+6lsAAA=
```

This is the Id of the attachment OfficeJS API told us existed in the email.

```
AAMkADRjMDhiMjI1LWZiMDYtNDFjOS1hODY1LWNjYWI4ODIyNTdjZQBGAAAAAAD6BIgnGKX9T7ArUySXdtR8BwAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AAAAAAEMAAAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AADX+0KqAAABEgAQAJ3qHJiNqoxEnYhbU77EaDE=
```

However these are the 3 attachment Ids that were returned by the EWS service

```
AAMkADRjMDhiMjI1LWZiMDYtNDFjOS1hODY1LWNjYWI4ODIyNTdjZQBGAAAAAAD6BIgnGKX9T7ArUySXdtR8BwAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AAANunoYAAAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AADX+6lsAAABEgAQAICb3poqh/xJieLT/Rsw59Y=

AAMkADRjMDhiMjI1LWZiMDYtNDFjOS1hODY1LWNjYWI4ODIyNTdjZQBGAAAAAAD6BIgnGKX9T7ArUySXdtR8BwAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AAANunoYAAAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AADX+6lsAAABEgAQAM1cKd+mL05NqJmTQa+Ads4=

AAMkADRjMDhiMjI1LWZiMDYtNDFjOS1hODY1LWNjYWI4ODIyNTdjZQBGAAAAAAD6BIgnGKX9T7ArUySXdtR8BwAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AAANunoYAAAzmyFPpmt3R5gtojict5n/AADX+6lsAAABEgAQAJ3qHJiNqoxEnYhbU77EaDE=
```

Comment: Have you tried using Graph API instead?

Comment: (1) From which platform you are using Office JS API: Outlook Win32, Outlook Mac, OWA, Mobile? (2) Are you checking attachment Ids always in Read-Mode? (3) Can you please share example of attachmentIds given by Office JS API and EWS API when it is different?

Comment: (1) We do not exactly know what p[platform was used as it was reported by our clients. It either Outlook Win32 or Outlook Mac.  
(2) We are always checking attachment Ids in Read Mode. Not in compose mode.
(3) Edited the question and added the attachment Ids from both OfficeJS and EWS.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Edited the question and added details in the comment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We would like to know that the 3 different attachment ID's you have shared in case of EWS are from:
1.  3 different EWS requests for the same attachment OR
2.   If the item has 3 attachments and a single request is returning all 3 ID's OR
3.   EWS request is somehow returning 3 ID's for one attachment

Comment: The email item had 3 attachments. We were only interested in 1 of the attachments. We made 1 EWS call and it returned Ids for all 3 attachments. However the attachment Id that OfficeJS API told us existed didn't come back from EWS call.

Comment: 1. Can you please confirm the platform you are experiencing it?
2. The third EWS id returned has the same attachment id part of the id as office.js. The only difference is the part of the id that is the item id. The part of the id that changed is the item id. Did you move the item to a new folder (which would cause the item id to change) ?